# Proving Jensens Inequality (Induction)

Tags: induction, convex-analysis

I am trying to prove Jensen's inequality, I have already proved the base cases for $n=1$, $n=2$ & $n=3$ now I am working on the inductive hypothesis and inductive step.

Let's Assume for $n$ less than and equal to $3$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{a_if(x_i)}≤f(\sum_{i=1}^n{a_ix_i})$$
Now show that $n=k+1$
So I write.. Since I am looking to prove the case where $n=k+1$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{a_if(x_i)}≤f(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{a_ix_i})$$
(Now from here onward is where I'm lost)
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{a_if(x_i)}≤f(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{a_ix_i})$$
 So then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{a_if(x_i)}≤f(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{a_ix_i})=f(a_1x_1+(1-x_i)\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{\frac{a_ix_i}{1-x_i}} )$$

But then i'm not sure where to go from here? I'm not even sure If I have the right approach. I was told that this was a simple proof/exercise but it doesn't seem like it at all.

Comment: I assume $f$ is concave. It looks like for the case $n=k+1$, you are starting out assuming what you want to prove!

Comment: You can assume that $a_1\neq 1$. Then you can talk about $\frac{1}{1-a_1}$.  In general, the idea is that the inequality you want to prove for $n=k+1$ should be obtainable from the $n=k$ and/or $n=2$ cases.

Comment: hmm.. I haven't done induction in quite  a while unfortunately so I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: So i don't need the n=k+1? should i go directly from line 1 to line 4?

Comment: First clarify what it is you are assuming in the "let's assume."  For example, what conditions are on the $a_i$?  Are the $x_i$ scalars or vectors? (Note that if they are vectors, it makes no sense to write $\frac{1}{1-x_i}$).  Next, replace "so I write" with "I want to prove that"

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but I assume it is from someone noticing we have no idea what conditions are on $f$, what the $a_i$ and $x_i$ are, and so on.

Comment: @Michael you're fine.. I'm trying to collect my thoughts at the moment. All I know about $a_i$ is that their sum equals 1. and that they are positive

Comment: @Michael am I on the right track at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in correct order, then finish the proof:

1. Suppose $a_1 \neq 1$. (If $a_1=1$ then...)
2. Fix $m$ as a positive integer.  Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a concave function.
3. Claim: $f(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i) \geq \sum_{i=1}^n a_i f(x_i)$ for all positive integers $n$, for all vectors $x_1, …, x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$, and all scalars $a_1, …, a_n$ that are nonnegative and satisfy …
4. We have:

\begin{align}
f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i x_i\right) &= f\left(a_1 x_1 + (1-a_1)\underbrace{\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}\frac{a_i}{1-a_1} x_i}_{z}\right) \\
&\geq …
\end{align}

5. Let $x_1, …, x_{k+1}$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and let $a_1, …, a_{k+1}$ be nonnegative scalars that sum to 1.
6. Suppose it holds for $n=k$, with $k\in \{1, 2, 3\}$.  We want to prove it for $n=k+1$.

Comment: @Temirzhan:  You can now answer this more structured exercise as your own answer below [it is common for askers to answer their own questions based on hints.]  It is best if you actually re-type the sentences I wrote above verbatim (filling in the blank parts where needed). This will give you appreciation for clearly declaring your variables and providing other necessary details.